# How can I hide a button in the Main form depending on the person logging in?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, sql-server-ce

I'm new to programming and using `SQL Server Compact` and I'm doing this personal project to learn, so any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to hide the `button` in the `Main Form` depending on the user type account that successfully logging.

In my database i have 3 columns which are `username`, `password` and `type - (this is what I am trying to access for this project)`.

I figured that to get the effect that I want I would have to deal with the Main_load so this is where I placed this code:

```
    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        admincontrolbtn.Visible = false;
        conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=Users.sdf; Persist Security Info = False");
        comm = new SqlCeCommand("Select * from [user]", conn);
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                if (reader.GetString(2) == "Administrator")
                {
                    admincontrolbtn.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    admincontrolbtn.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I built the code no error was found. I thought that I was on the right track. But when I logged in using a credential that has a `User" type`, the `button` was still visible.
I have already tried to debug the code by putting a break right on the `Main_load` itself but when i run it and log in, it goes to display the Main page ignoring the Main_load altogether.

I have also tried to set the visibility of the `button` to false it the properties but when the main page loads, even using the **Administrator** type of credential, the `button` stays hidden.

Was the syntax of the code wrong? and/or maybe my way of thinking that `Main_load` is my target wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when the user logs in you make a user object that holds all relevant information for that user. Then later you won't have to access the database every time you want to know something about your user.

```
class User
{
  string role;
  //.. other user attributes.
}
```

Your command should be different in that you only want information on one user:

```
comm = new SqlCeCommand("Select * from [user] where user_id=1", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have already tried to debug the code by putting a break right on the
>   Main_load itself but when i run it and log in, it goes to display the
>   Main page ignoring the Main_load altogether.

This usually means that your method `Main_Load` is not binded to [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event fo the form. Check how you handle form [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event (if you handle it) and fix the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this helped. i double clicked on the form again to create a new Load event to be sure then I did what @Mr.Fox said. (Although I did that too but it didnt work the first time I did it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this could not have thrown an `SqlException`; for two reasons:

1. The SQL you have written does not seem right and
2. If it was right it seems you would be expecting mulitple restults (using `*`), in this case using `while (reader.Read()) { ... }` will loop through each result and set the logic accordingly. So, if the first user you had was `USER` and the second `Administrator`, the button enabled state would be set according to the last accessed value - not what you want.

Instead, set up a static utilities class to help with SQL queries. So you would have some thing like

```
public static calss Utilities
{
    public static bool SQLResult(SqlConnection conn, string strSQL)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
            strResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Return error or display.
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

where this method will expect to return a single text result.

Now the SQL you want to use is

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER;
GO
```

This will return the current logged in user; the user executing the query. For me it returns 'ServerName\Administrator'. So your logic could be

```
string sql = "SELECT SYSTEM_USER;";
string result = Utilities.SQLResult(someValidConnection, sql);
if (result.Contains("Administrator"))
    // Do stuff.
```

I hope this helps.

*Note. The above does not consider SQL Injection attacks or other security issues. For most basic WinForm applications (non-webbased) these security issues are IMO not worth worrying about.*

Comment: Thank you, its working now thanks to Mr.Fox and Tigran, but I learned from reading your post and I will try your approach right now.